# How to send mail to multiple user using Nodemailer And Firebase asynchronously

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, nodemailer

I ve tried different loop function to send mail from my cloud database.
the code below sends the mail **but**
I can't send mail that contain details specific to each recipiant

I want to loop through my database collection and send mails asynchronously.

````
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

////we would use receipt for the testing of the loop

//google account credentials used to send email
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.example.com",
    port: 587,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: '***********@fastfood.com',
        pass: '********'
    }
});
exports.newsletters = functions.firestore
.document('Puns/{orderId}')
.onWrite((snap, context)=> {
     var Emails = ['Cyrilogoh@gmail.com', 'mariajame34@gmail.com','therealogoh@gmail.com','faraway@gmail.com']
const mailOptions = {
    from: `cyrilogoh@gmail.com`,
    to: Emails,
    subject: `test`,
    html: `<h1>test</h1>
                        <p>
                          Array Works 
                        </p>`                              

};
return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error)
        return
    }
    console.log("Sent!")
});
});```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you can get the data from your recently added document on the `snapshot` object being passed to your `onWrite` call.

Without more details on your firestore structure and what kind of data you getting, here is a snippet that can help you start building your async email call:

```
//google account credentials used to send email
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.example.com",
    port: 587,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
        user: '***********@fastfood.com',
        pass: '********'
    }
});

exports.newsletters = functions.firestore.document('Puns/{orderId}').onWrite((snapshot, context)=> {

    var document = snapshot.data();

    //data to be added on the email body (could be anything)
    var data = document.body

    const mailOptions = {
        from: `cyrilogoh@gmail.com`,
        to: document.email,
        subject: `test`,
        //add whatever data you want here
        html: data
    };
    return transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, data) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error)
            return
        }
        console.log("Sent!")
    });
})
```

You can get user specific data inside the document object to check which user should receive each email, assuming the collection has that data or reference to a userId to be searched on a different collection.

Hope This helps.

Comment: Thanks, It really helped in remodelling. But am not conversant with http trigger, and my intentions after first was to use the onwrite function to trigger the newsletter function from another collection.... (yea I know, bad practice), so i was wondering if you could like write it regard to a cloud function and ignore the array, its was me testing. THANKS AGAIN

Comment: Ok, I have edited the answer to use the `onWrite` trigger, it does not change a whole lot, you just need to operate the data you get from the snapshot object inside the function. If this is what you are looking for, remember to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark.